# Comparing dates in Python - how to handle time zone modifiers

Tags: python, date, datetime, python-2.7

I am doing Python date comparizon:

Assume I have a date like this: `'Fri Aug 17 12:34:00 2012 +0000'`

I am parsing it in the following manner:

`dt=datetime.strptime('Fri Aug 17 12:34:00 2012 +0000', '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y +0000')`

I could not find on the documentation page how to handle the remaining `+0000`?
I want to have a more generic solution then hardcoded value.

Perhaps this is quite easy, any hint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default `datetime` module does *not* handle timezones very well; beyond your current machine timezone and UTC, they are basically not supported.

You'll have to use an external library for that or handle the timezone offset manually.

External library options:

- Use [`dateutil.parser`](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-a23e8ae0a661d77b89dfb3476f85b26f0b30349c) can handle just about any date and or time format you care to throw at it:

  ```
  from dateutil import parser

  dt = parser.parse(s)
  ```
- The [`iso8601` library](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/iso8601/) handles only ISO 8601 formats, which include timezone offsets of the same form:

  ```
  import iso8601
  datetimetext, tz = s.rsplit(None, 1)  # only grab the timezone portion.
  timezone = iso8601.iso8601.parse_timezone('{}:{}'.format(tz[:3], tz[3:]))
  dt = datetime.strptime(datetimetext, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y').replace(tzinfo=timezone)
  ```

Demonstration of each approach:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> s = 'Fri Aug 17 12:34:00 2012 +0000'
>>> import iso8601
>>> timezone = iso8601.iso8601.parse_timezone('{}:{}'.format(tz[:3], tz[3:]))
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(datetimetext, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y').replace(tzinfo=timezone)
datetime.datetime(2012, 8, 17, 12, 34, tzinfo=<FixedOffset '+00:00'>)
>>> from dateutil import parser
>>> parser.parse(s)
datetime.datetime(2012, 8, 17, 12, 34, tzinfo=tzutc())
```

Answer (score 3):

You might want also give [Delorean](http://delorean.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#truncation) a look. Which is a wrapper around both `pytz` and `dateutil` it provides timezone manipulation as well as easy datetime time zone shift.

Here is how I would solve your question with Delorean.

```
>>> from delorean import parse
>>> parse("2011/01/01 00:00:00 -0700")
Delorean(datetime=2011-01-01 07:00:00+00:00, timezone=UTC)
```

From there you can return the datetime by simply return the `.datetime` attribute. If you wan to do some time shifts simply use the Delorean object and do `.shift("UTC")` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `dateutil.parser`:

```
>>> import dateutil.parser
>>> dateutil.parser.parse('Fri Aug 17 12:34:00 2012 +0000')
>>> datetime.datetime(2012, 8, 17, 12, 34, tzinfo=tzutc())
```