# Convert a ctime (like) timestamp into a tz aware datetime instance

Tags: python, datetime

I have timestamps in the following format

```
"Sat Feb 06 07:00:13 -0800 2010"
```

What is the idiomatic/pythonic way to convert this kind of timestamp into tz aware datetime instance? ... I've fiddled with the single parts of the timestamp but looks all ugly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't parse time zones with `datetime`. But you can use the `dateutil.parser` module instead, as shown below. It returns a `datetime.datetime` object.

```
>>> dateutil.parser.parse('Sat Feb 06 07:00:13 -0800 2010')
datetime.datetime(2010, 2, 6, 7, 0, 13, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -28800))
```

And to be fair, see this [complete answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14958976/2009616).